# Can I install emscripten with python3

Tags: 18.04, python, python3, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in Windows Subsystem for Linux on my Windows 10 laptop. Feels very very linuxy so far.

But the main thing I wanted to use it for at first is [Emscripten](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/downloads.html) to learn WebAssembly. As such I want to keep things minimal, and when that's not possible, I at least want to fully understand why.

This Ubuntu comes with Python 3 installed by default as "python3", and Python 2 is optional. Apparently [Emscripten does support Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54897879/what-version-of-python-is-need-to-install-emscripten).

It installs fine and I follow the docs to test the installation by going to the `~/emsdk/fastcomp/emscripten` dir and entering the command `./emcc -v` but get the error:

`/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory`

Adding an alias from python to python three had no effect. Next I tried `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /us
r/bin/python3 10` which changed the error output to this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hippietrail/emsdk/fastcomp/emscripten/emcc.py", line 41, in <module>
    import emscripten
  File "/home/hippietrail/emsdk/fastcomp/emscripten/emscripten.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tools import shared
  File "/home/hippietrail/emsdk/fastcomp/emscripten/tools/shared.py", line 8, in <module>
    from distutils.spawn import find_executable
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.spawn'
```

Googling doesn't find anybody else with this problem but I'm not ready to give up and install Python 2 yet.

Next I tried installing the "upstream" version of Emscripten rather than the default "fastcomp" thinking maybe the Python3 fix is only in newer versions. But this has not changed the error output.

Any ideas what to try next? My *nix knowledge has gotten very very rusty by the way.